# Missing codepage for table when using dataserver

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

### Problem

I use dataserver to create records in MSSQL. I transfer data in bulk, with `for each`. Lets say tens of records. As I transfer those records with `buffer-copy`, I can easily verify the transfer with `buffer-compare`.

For unknown reasons, **some** records are malformed. When this happens, **all** consecutive records get malformed as well. This malformation means that `character` fields transfer with chinese characters in them. The first record that does this is only partially malformed. Meaning that some fields are ok, one is partially ok with the rest in chinese, and the rest of fields are completely in chinese. Character fields of all other records get malformed completely.

I am not able to artificially produce this, there is no known (to me) character or character sequence that does this. For a while we believed that it was `chr(10)` and replacing it with an empty string solved the problem. But it is back again.

### Code I use to do it

Lets say I have a source `oe_table` in OpenEdge database, `ms_table` in MSSQL which I access through DataServer. Following code example is slightly modified excerpt from the actual program:

[image: Code example]
or here: https://pastebin.com/MFF4FEQ3

Note: The actual `for each` has `where` clausule and the `buffer-copy` has `except` option for two fields (of course this is reflected in `buffer-compare` also).

Note: We came up with the idea to `raw-transfer` the record, because we could not find anything strange in the fields specified by `cUnequalFields`.

### What we discovered

Contents of `oe_table.bin`: [image: Contents of oe_table]
Contents of `ms_table.bin`: [image: Contents of ms_table]
Contents of `tt_table.bin`: [image: Contents of tt_table]
Contents of `ms_table_ok.bin`, when the record does not get malformed (as to how did I get that record to not get malformed, I will get to that later): [image: Contents of ms_table_ok.bin]

The obvious thing here is this: `oe_table` and `tt_table` has a codepage specified, while `ms_table` does not. It is even more obvious when comparing the the record in `ms_table` that gets malformed with the exact same record in `ms_table_ok` that **does not get malformed**. While the `ms_table_ok` has `UTF-8` specified, the `ms_table` does not have any.

Another interesting thing - look at the `0x250` row in `ms_table` and compare it to the `0x260` row in `ms_table_ok`. Look at the data "system". For some reason, `ms_table` treats it as single-byte, while the `ms_table_ok` treats it as double-byte. Also, `ms_table` does this even though it is not the first character field in the table. So he treats the preceeding field as double-byte, then treats this one as single-byte, then continues to treat remaining fields as double-byte again.

Next thing I just realized is that "utf-8", which is in `ms_table` missing, takes five bytes. That is odd number. That may explain different interpretation of strings later on. Look at row `0x320` and `0x330` in `ms_table` and `ms_table_ok` respectively. While the `ms_table_ok` represents single-byte characters in double-byte interpretation as `d.`, the `ms_table` represents it the other way as `.d`. That is one byte shift.

### How did I get the fine version of the record

This is also very strange. I experimented with startup parameters on the DataServer. Adding `-Dsrv qt_no_debug` or any other `-Dsrv qt_debug` means I can transfer the record without a problem, while not having that parameter means it will get malformed. That is the strangest thing in all this by far for me. So with this, I managed to get the `ms_table_ok` for comparison.

Then we have the same problem on another dataserver, where this parameter thing does not work at all.

### Sorry, what was the question again?

The question is: What is the reason for the codepage not to be specified in the transfer?

Because that looks like the real issue here. But maybe I am not right and am missing something? Or do you have any idea what else can I try? I was convinced that the dataserver settings are not right, but then it works with that parameter and it works for other tables.

I will appreciate **ANY** advice! Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched knowledgebase.progress.com (use google - not internal crappy search)? Lots of dataserver + codepage related entries.

Comment: @Jensd I did find similar issues. I think three of them. I checked our setup against them, but it looked fine. I will give it another shot.

Comment: If you're on an active license you should also contact support. https://www.progress.com/support/openedge